# Vue router static param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want pass some information through url in vue router, such as

`http://localhost/center/SHOPID/products
http://localhost/center/SHOPID/categories
http://localhost/center/SHOPID/...`

SHOPID will not be changed in whole SPA instance life cycle, but different SPA instance may have different SHOPID because I can't store SHOPID in localStorage to avoid SPA instance influences each other. How can I make SHOPID transparent in my code. Such as `vm.$router.push({name:'center.product'})` will get url `http://localhost/center/SHOPID/products` where SHOPID always be static.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the route path instead of the route name?

Comment: @StevenSpungin If I push the route path, I need to generate the path first, in this case I must get SHOPID and handle it.

Comment: You could simply use https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Comment: @soju The base urls should be different if SHOPIDs are different.

Comment: I don't see the problem, you should create your router instance accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I use query string to resolve my question. With url `http://localhost/?shopId=123#/products`. I parsed query string when app startup and store shopId in a global object for accessing latter. When the hash string changed, the query string will be static.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your path params like this:

```
router.push({ name: 'center.product', params: { SHOPID: theShopId }})
```

Or you can just push the path, using string replacement text.

```
router.push({ path: `center/${theShopId}/products` })
```

This assumes you defined your path using params.

```
center/:SHOPID/products
```

You can also put a navigation guard in place, and redirect to a different route, adding your SHOPID from the session

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: 'center/products',
      component: Products,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        next({ name: 'center.product', params: { SHOPID: $store.state.shopId }})
      }
```

or use query instead of path params

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: 'center/products',
      component: Products,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        next({ name: 'center.product', query: { shopId: $store.state.shopId }})
      }
```

When you push `center/products` it will be rerouted using the the shop id from your store, context, session, database, etc.

Comment: So I need to deal with SHOPID every where if I need to change route? Or do you have other solutions to make a string static in url such as query string?

Comment: I updated answer with an indirection that fills in the shopID using a nav guard.

Comment: That's a good idea to use navigation guard. I will try to use a global navigation guard to handle all routes with SHOPID. Thank you!

Comment: I can't change params in beforeEach guard.

Comment: I found that it is hard to keep shopId when window refreshed. I can't get the shopId when the guard first triggered unless parse the route manully. So I used query string. It's easy to parse by query-string module and will not change when route changed.

Comment: Are you still using nav guard, but with query params?

Comment: No, I'm using query params. I posted my answer.

Comment: So you still need to specify 'SHOPID everywhere if I need to change route', yes?

Comment: Yes, so that I can get the SHOPID if I refresh the page always. If I store the SHOPID in localStorage the pages will share it and cause many issues.

Comment: So you could still use nav guard to generate query instead of params.  The would be better than hard coding.  I updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `meta` fields for this. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Example from the docs:

```
routes = [
  {
     path: 'sample',
     meta: { shopId: 'id' }
  }
];
```